# Getting code-first entity framework Azure back in sync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I've been playing with Azure and MVC5/EF6 with Code First migrations and managed to find something that I wouldn't know how to fix if it was production.

Here's what I did:

1. Create a model named `MyModel` with one property: `PropA`
2. Enabled migrations and created a migration named `Initial`
3. Published to Azure - great - works fine!
4. Deleted my `Initial` migration and added a second property to `MyModel` named `PropB`
5. Created a new migration called `Initial2`
6. Published to Azure - now azure is crashing because it can't find the field `PropB`

I've tried setting `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` but it didn't make any difference.

So my question is: **If this were a production database and this happened - how would you get the Azure database back in sync and migrate the changed models?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually add code to the migration in the "up" and "down" methods to sync your code as required

Comment: I guess I can do that - what if there is a load of tables that are missing though? Is there any automated way except SQL compare?

Comment: SQL Compare seems to be the easiest option here.

Answer (score 0):

Before you use SQL compare, be sure that you're running at least a "standard" database tier in Azure.  If not, you'll get errors just trying to do the compare.  Note that you can change your tier, do some commands, and change the tier back within a few minutes.

Also, in your list of steps, after step 5, do an `update-database`.  That will get your local database in sync.  Next, when you publish to Azure, make sure to select that database (dropdown next to the connection string), and then be sure that `execute code-first migrations` is checked.

Cheers